# Evaluate the antiderivative at a particular point without integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $g(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}\:$   and $\:g(3)=0$, what is $g(6)$? $\:\:\:$If it were a function I could integrate, it'd be a snap - but not this one.
It feels like it should be relatively easy and using FTC 2. I'm sure I'm missing the obvious...
Can anyone help?
Thanks!!
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$g(x)=\int_a^x\frac{e^t}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ for some value of $a$. Since $g(3)=0$ it must be that $a=3$, and $$g(6)=\int_3^6\frac{e^t}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$$  I don't see how one can do any better than this.

Comment: Ha!  And there was much rejoicing. Thank you!